# IF ELSE or use Case or a combination of both

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Tried to figure this out but not sure how to do this correct.

I need to check first if **Attended** and **Barcode** are correct in table Events if so it will update.

If not it needs to check whats not correct:

If  **Attended** is not correct then select @Err

If **Barcode** is not correct then select @Err2

I am not sure if this is the best approach.
Thanks in advance.

```
-- Returns scan details
    DECLARE @Err nvarchar(Max) = 'Already scanned'
    DECLARE @Err2 nvarchar(Max) = 'Barcode not found'

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[Events] WHERE Attended = '0' AND Barcode = @scan))
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[Events] SET Attended = GETDATE() WHERE Barcode = @scan
            SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Constituency, Category, Barcode, EventDate, EventName, Attended FROM [Test].[dbo].[Events] WHERE Barcode = @scan
            END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    -- select @Err
    END
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on this `If not it needs to check whats not correct.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
-- Returns scan details
DECLARE @Err nvarchar(Max) = 'Already scanned'
DECLARE @Err2 nvarchar(Max) = 'Barcode not found'

IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[Events] WHERE Attended = '0' AND Barcode = @scan))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[Events] SET Attended = GETDATE() WHERE Barcode = @scan
        SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Constituency, Category, Barcode, EventDate, EventName, Attended FROM [Test].[dbo].[Events] WHERE Barcode = @scan
    END
ELSE IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[Events] WHERE Barcode = @scan))
    BEGIN
        select @Err
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Err2
    END
```

Regards.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so simple when someone else just points it out Thanks Victor.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark this answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: check the answer i modified it

Comment: I dont accept the edit suggested because only change the logic of "exists" anr replaced for "not exists"

Comment: u sure that the above condition are satisfied such as -                                  
If Attended is not correct then select Err

If Barcode is not correct then select  Err2